# Kentico image API - Need to return image URL instead of Guid in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kentico

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please excuse me if title or question is not good.

At the moment I got VoucherResponse class

```
  public class VoucherResponse
{
    public int VoucherID { get; set; }
    public string VoucherTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VoucherVariant> VoucherVariants { get; set; }
    public string[] VoucherImages { get; set; }
}
```

And Web api method

```
 return Ok(from v in distinctby
                     select new VoucherResponse
                     {
                         VoucherID = v.VoucherID,
                         VoucherTitle = v.VoucherTitle,
                         VoucherVariants = (from voucher in voucherToLookup[v.VoucherID]
                                            select new VoucherVariant 
                                            {
                                                VoucherDiscountedPrice = voucher.VoucherPrice  - (voucher.VoucherPrice * voucher.VoucherDiscount/ 100),
                                                VoucherVariantId = voucher.VoucherVariantId,
                                                VoucherPrice = voucher.VoucherPrice,
                                                VoucherStock = 1

                                            }),
                         VoucherImages = (from image in distinctby
                                          where v.VoucherID == image.VoucherID
                                          select image.VoucherImages

                                          // URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(ModuleCommands.MediaLibraryGetMediaFileUrl(image.FileGUID, voucher.NodeAlias + "_" + image.ImageOrder))).ToArray(),
                                          ).ToArray()
                     });
```

At the moment I am getting results

```
{
"voucherID": 380,
"voucherTitle": "Woolworths e-Gift Card",
"voucherVariants": [
  {
    "voucherVariantId": 397,
    "voucherPrice": 100,
    "voucherDiscountedPrice": 95,
    "voucherStock": 1
  },
  {
    "voucherVariantId": 389,
    "voucherPrice": 200,
    "voucherDiscountedPrice": 190,
    "voucherStock": 1
  },
  {
    "voucherVariantId": 393,
    "voucherPrice": 300,
    "voucherDiscountedPrice": 285,
    "voucherStock": 1
  },
  {
    "voucherVariantId": 394,
    "voucherPrice": 400,
    "voucherDiscountedPrice": 380,
    "voucherStock": 1
  },
  {
    "voucherVariantId": 395,
    "voucherPrice": 500,
    "voucherDiscountedPrice": 475,
    "voucherStock": 1
  }
],
"voucherImages": [
  " B4A3A070-3ED1-4086-8B33-21465AA58C7A, 2FB01963-2D71-4C79-9EE8-38A114CAF1A6"
]
```

I need to return voucherImages like this

```
    "VoucherImages" : [
{"www.kentico.info/imageOne.jpg"}
{"www.kentico.info/imageTwo.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Why don't you format the data like that and return it?

Comment: The problem is in title and also last paragraph. Not sure how to make it work

Comment: Where do you store the images? (Media library / attachments / file page type...?) Or which form control do you use to store the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for trying to help me.
I resolved this problem by myself.
@rocky images are stored in media library, I created method that seams to be working but I still getting "ugly url" like
"http://localhost:50848/getmedia/8f5f2e87-782c-4ee2-b6c0-dba614588fe4/
I would like to get something like "http://localhost:50848/getmedia/image1.jpg
But will do research on this, if anyone need the code in the feature i will paste method below

```
  private string[] GetImageURLs(string guids, string voucherTitle)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string[] guid = guids.Split(',');
        string alias, url,image;

        foreach (var item in guid)
        {
            url = ModuleCommands.MediaLibraryGetMediaFileUrl(ValidationHelper.GetGuid(item, Guid.Empty), SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
            image = URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(url);
            result.Add(image);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```